# Why I can't set an image src dynamically after component is mounted?

Tags: reactjs

I have this component where I randomly get an image path from database and want to set it as an image src, although if I manually type

```
<image src={require('../../assets/images/img1.jpg)}
```

it works but this way it isn't working

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./PreviewContainer.scss";
import axios from "axios";
export default function PreviewContainer() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState({ path: "../../assets/", render: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("getPreview", true);
    axios.post("http://localhost/imageAPI/index.php", formData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setImage({ path: image.path + response.data, render: true });
    });
  }, []);
  return <div className="preview-container">{image.render ? <img src={require(`${image.path}`)}></img> : null}</div>;
}
```

response.data returns images/img1.jpg, why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe you need to append `../../assets/` to `response.data` ?

Comment: @Hackerman I am doing such 
setImage({ path: image.path + response.data, render: true });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully dynamic path to `require` is not supported. You need to provide webpack with some static path so it has idea about where your assets are located.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./PreviewContainer.scss";
import axios from "axios";
export default function PreviewContainer() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState({ name:'', render: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("getPreview", true);
    axios.post("http://localhost/imageAPI/index.php", formData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setImage({ name: response.data.split('/')[-1], render: true });
    });
  }, []);
  return <div className="preview-container">{image.render ? <img src={require(`../../assets/images/${image.name}`)}></img> : null}</div>;
}
```

Comment: @BrandNew Glad it help Brand, please don't forget to give the answer an upvote too if it helps :)

Comment: I did  upvote but 
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
require('../../assets/images/img1.jpg')
```

This works because on built-time, the require/import is replaced with the relative path of the actual file.
If require/import is not used, then compiler can't transform it. By transformation, I mean replacing the file location from the source with the static location.

```
const [image, setImage] = useState({ path: "../../assets/", render: false });
```

Here, `../../assets/` is not imported or required, so the compiler can't any build-time transformation.

If you really need to use dynamic access, require each resource and build a dictionary. Then you can generate a dynamic key based on the selection.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./PreviewContainer.scss";
import axios from "axios";

const imgs = {
  "img1": require('../../assets/images/img1.jpg'),
  "img2": require('../../assets/images/img2.jpg'),
  "img3": require('../../assets/images/img3.jpg'),
  "img4": require('../../assets/images/img4.jpg'),
  "img5": require('../../assets/images/img5.jpg'),
}

export default function PreviewContainer() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState({ path: "", render: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("getPreview", true);
    axios.post("http://localhost/imageAPI/index.php", formData).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setImage({ path: imgs[response.data], render: true });
    });
  }, []);
  return <div className="preview-container">{image.render ? <img src={image.path}></img> : null}</div>;
}
```

By requiring the assets inside the dictionary, the compiler will be able to replace the relative path with the static path of the assets.